# Problem in limit of exponential function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to obtain

```
Exp[-α/(1 - α)] /. {α -> 1}
```

The output is `Indeterminate`. But I calculate without Mathematica and I obtain 0.

$$-\frac{1}{0} \rightarrow -\infty \implies e^{-\infty} \rightarrow 0$$

For another example, please consider

```
Limit[-(-1 + E^((t*α)/(-1 + α)))*x/α, α -> 1, Direction -> 1]
```

$x$ is real and $t > 0$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to take the `Limit`.

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer I have problem with this limit  `Limit[-(((-1 + E^((t*\[Alpha])/(-1 + \[Alpha])))*x)/\[Alpha]), \[Alpha] -> 1, Direction -> 1]`

Comment: Please add that info to the question. What do you know about `x` and `t`? Are they real? Are they positive? Negative? Add that to the question also.

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer Many thanks. I edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide those important `Assumptions` to `Limit`, it will correctly compute that the exponential goes to zero, as you already know:

```
Limit[
 -(((-1 + E^((t*α)/(-1 + α)))*x)/α), α -> 1, 
 Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> t > 0 && Element[x, Reals]
]
(* x *)
```

This is explained in the [documentation for `Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) -> Examples -> Options -> Assumptions. By the way, I think one usually prefers to use `Exp[x]` instead of `E^(x)`.

Comment: Lukas, why would it make a difference whether one uses `Exp[x]`, or `E^x`? As far as I know, they are perfectly equivalent, and one of the two is converted into the other automatically anyway.

Comment: @MarcoB I honestly think it is cleaner and easier to read. Might be just my opinion... But for instance in this example there are already so many parentheses that the square brackets for `Exp` clearly separate the exponential from the rest. You're of course right with that it does not affect computations :)